# STS does not allow me to select framework version 4

Tags: spring-tool-suite

Is it correct that STS does allow me to select spring framework version 4 when I create a new "Spring Framework" project ?

I have version 3.6.3.SR1 of the Spring Tool Suite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like some wizards are and may not allow to select the latest Spring Framework from the UI. You can still open pom.xml once the project is created and fix the Spring Framework version in it.
It is advised to use the new "Create Spring Starter Project" wizard available from the Dashboard as well as from the standard File -> New.